# how to use curl url header in android

Tags: android

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta
```

http request code to authenticate above curl?

```
httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username:password" ),HTTP.UTF_8, false));
```

is this correct? I am not getting output

Comment: Kandhasamy - What is the error your seeing after executing your curl command. Your syntax seems ok though.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question if below was not an answer to the problem

Answer (score 0):

public static String getRequest() {

```
    String countstring;

    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();

        URI uri = new URI("https://XXXXXXXXX.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=status=open");
        httpGet.setURI(uri);
        httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("XXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXX"),
                HTTP.UTF_8, false));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                inputStream));

        String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (readLine != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(readLine);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
            readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("oindi");
    }

    finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("numbers3 :"+ stringBuffer.toString());

    JSONObject entries=null;
    String jsontext;
    jsontext=stringBuffer.toString();
    int india = jsontext.length();
    System.out.println("india" +india);
    try {
        entries = new JSONObject(jsontext);


        int lat = entries.getInt("total");

        System.out.println("latttttttttttttttt"+lat);

        countstring=String.valueOf(lat);

        System.out.println("numbers4"+ countstring);

    }
    catch (JSONException w)
    {
        w.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exceptionnnnnnnnnn 3");
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account details are incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: above one is the code...throwing exception and integer india is zero

Comment: Please explain how this answers your question for future readers instead of a code dump